# Proportionality In two Values Equal to $0$

Tags: arithmetic

If two values $m$ and $n$ are in direct variation, then

> $m \propto n$

If the constant of proportionality is $q$ between them, then

> $m = qn$

If $m$ and $n$ both are equal to zero or $m = 0$ and $n = 0$, then will they be called directly proportional to each other?

Comment: Yes, though one would probably do so only if they at least *could* be nonzero.

Comment: The concept isn't much use in that case... you could extend it to that case, if convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but trivially so, in that the constant of proportionality can be any non-zero real number.  That simply means than the direct proportionality of $m = n = 0$ is independent of the constant of proportionality $q$.

Typically, the sole restriction for two variables $m, n$ to be directly proportional is  that the constant of proportionality, $q$ in your case, is non-zero.

See [direct proportionality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportionality_%28mathematics%29#Direct_proportionality) for more information.

Comment: But in this case $m = n$, then why should we say _ Proportional_?

Comment: Two variables that are equal are by default, proportional. For nonzero $m = n$, this just means that the constant of proportionality is $1$...Here is a situation where we can convey just as much information (and more) about the relationship between $m$ and $n$ by stating $m = n$ than by stating $m, n$ are "proportional"

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can I ask you for your email address?

Comment: I'd be happy to talk with you in a private chat sometime, when we both have the time...that's easy enough to set up...let me know some times that would be good for you...

Comment: @amWhy: Nice write-up and exchange! +1